# Convert system time to New York time zone

Tags: r

Is there a way to convert Sys.time to New york time zone in R?. I tried with following, but did not work

```
as.POSIXct(Sys.time(), tz="EDT")
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Sys.time()`, the time zone is already included in the string:

```r
Sys.time()
#> [1] "2020-09-18 08:56:56 BST"
```

If you want to convert that time to a different timezone, you can set its "tzone" attribute:

```r
`attr<-`(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()), "tzone", "EST")
#> [1] "2020-09-18 02:57:23 EST"
```

My system doesn't recognise "EDT" as a named time zone. I have to do:

```r
`attr<-`(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()), "tzone", "America/New_York")
#> [1] "2020-09-18 03:59:55 EDT"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display time in any time-zone using `format` :

```
time <- Sys.time()
format(time, tz="America/New_York",usetz=TRUE)
#[1] "2020-09-18 03:59:39 EDT"
#this works too
format(time, tz="US/Eastern",usetz=TRUE)
#[1] "2020-09-18 03:59:39 EDT"
```